# How mlxtend StackingRegressor with multiple cpu?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm, catboost, mlxtend

I would like to use mlxtend StackingRegressor to ensemble XGBoost,LGBM and Catboost  .But I am not sure how much cpu I will use in this method.

For example:

In XGboost:

```
import xgboost as xgb
xgb_pars = {'nthread': -1}
xgb1=XGBRegressor(**xgb_pars)
```

Then I know I will use up all cpu core in this algorithm

But what if I try it with mlxtend StackingRegressor?

I guess this method will use cpu that I arranged to each algorithm.

Example:
XGBoost:2 LGBM:2 CatBoost:2 Meta regressor:1

So finally I am using 7 cores.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, the code seems to fit models one after another, see [here](https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend/blob/93dee32f29b1a6d0f3e35945b9f8937c18f975b3/mlxtend/regressor/stacking_regression.py#L135). So first you will use 2 cores to train XGB, when it finishes- 2 cores for LGBM, and so on.

BTW, thanks for sharing mlxtend- i was not aware of it. Seems to have many useful tools, that i had to develop myself and thus to re-invent the wheel :) The only unfortunate thing seems to be missing docs, but there are inlined docs and a very good set of examples